# Overlay Map Visual on Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, overlay, mapping, power-bi

I am trying to display a map/shapefile of an NTS250k grid of Canada as shown in MS Power BI. BI requires to import the shapefile using .json format. I am just wondering if there is a way to be able to overlay a map of Canada onto this (without affecting the shape selection) so the user can see what it is they are looking at.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a basemap? According to this guide you would then need to choose a different native map than the Shape Map as it doesn't have that option:
https://dataveld.com/2017/06/03/10-ways-to-create-maps-in-microsoft-power-bi/

Comment: Was hoping for a way for it to be done using shape map - will have to settle on a different native map then. Thank you for the clarification!